# How can i ignore cases in react to filter data?

Tags: reactjs

I have written a code which filters the data but it filters with Case of the alphabet, i want to ignore the case and filter.

Here is what i have written-

```
let filteredcontacts = this.props.contacts.filter(
     (contact) => {
         val= contact.name.indexOf(this.state.search)!==-1;
});
```

Comment: case means uppercase, lowercase, you want to filter without checking the case ?

Comment: ya..i dont want it to be case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before filtering the data first convert the text into `lowercase` by using `toLocaleLowerCase()` then use `indexOf` on that to check the index.

Write it like this:

```
let filteredcontacts = this.props.contacts.filter(contact => {
       return contact.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
});
```

I think, inside `filter` it should be `contact.name` instead of `friend.name`.

Comment: Thank you @mayank Shukla